# What are the rules for the visibility of base class types in derived classes?

Tags: c++

I have a class like this

```
template <typename T>
class Parent
{
public:
    typedef T Value;
    typedef int Argument;

    virtual Value foo (Argument);

    class Child;
};

template <typename T>
class Parent <T> :: Child : public Parent <T>
{
public:
    Value foo (Argument) override;                 // (1)
};

template <typename T>
typename Parent <T> :: Child :: Value
Parent <T> :: Child :: foo (Argument arg)
{
    // ...
}
```

In fact I have a number of classes which follow approximately this pattern. Such code compiled and ran correctly.

Now I have added another pair of classes according to approximately the same pattern and I am getting some errors.

At (1) `error: ‘Value’ does not name a type`

In reality the actual classes are complex and proprietary so I can't post the details, but in order to solve this problem for myself, **where can I find the relevant C++ rules governing the visibility of parent types to nested and derived classes?**

Comment: `private` members are not visible to child classes, `protected` and `public` are. It's as simple as that. And remember that the default visibility for classes is `private`.

Comment: Edited. I forgot to put them in the example.

Comment: @user1810087 In that case it's a mystery why the previous classes *DO* work, and I still need the rules to figure *that* out.